# Why the name "Gumdrop" for the vintage car?

Tags: name-significance, val-biro, gumdrop

As a child I enjoyed some of the [Gumdrop stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumdrop_(book_series)), without ever realising that the name of the car Gumdrop was the same as [a type of sweet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumdrop). Perhaps the reason for this name is explained somewhere in the books and I've long forgotten it.

**Why was the car called Gumdrop?** It doesn't seem to *look* especially like a gumdrop sweet:

[image: image of the car Gumdrop, with owner and dog inside]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (defunct) Val Biro [*Official Fan web page*](http://cunninghamh.tripod.com/books/valbiro/valbiro-index.htm/#First) has a brief interview with Val Biro on this subject, adding to the wording found in *Gumdrop Makes a Start*.

> **HOW GUMDROP GOT HIS NAME**
>
> He set the levers on the steering wheel and pulled the choke out. Then
> he pressed his foot on the starter button. The car went "Guuuuum". The
> foreman pushed in the choke and pulled out the ignition button and
> pressed his foot again. This time the car went "Drrrropopopop" and the
> engine started.
>
> The boy was enchanted. What a lovely sound; "Guuuuum-Drrrropopopop".
> As if the car had called out his own name. "That's it!" he declared to
> one and all. "That's his name. GUMDROP!" and he felt convinced that
> Gumdrop was the only car for him.

This presumably is also the out-of-universe reason that Balint Stephen "Val" Biro named [his real-world car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Val_Biro#Gumdrop) (on which the book series is based).